# Lookback period for UTMA expenses

Tags: united-states, utma-ugma

Can I use a UTMA to pay for elementary and high school education for a child in prior years?  How far would the "look back" be?  I've incurred $5600 in the past 4 years, and a total of about 25K in the past 12 years.  I don't mind liquidating it and paying the taxes if I am able to.  I am an NJ resident.